# Sort by newest option

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is there any way to get back the option to sort answers in newest to oldest order?

Comment: You should do it with fake unicode spaces like the BOM to get around that noise.

Comment: I second the request for this feature!

Comment: Technically, this was implemented at some point, in a sense; you can sort by "Highest score", "Date modified (newest first)", or "Date created (oldest first)". That second option would do part of what you want, with the caveat that it also takes edits into account as well.

Answer (score -5):

Newest was [replaced with oldest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75301/50049) because it doesn't break bottom up viewing of questions that have multiple pages of answers. There was a bit of debate about which to have, since they're basically redundant. Others have [expressed profound grief](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134259/bring-back-the-newest-sort-order-for-answers) over its absence, but we're not very likely to change it.

As this would affect every site, this is something you'd probably want to propose on Meta SO as a feature request if you have a strong use case for changing it back. I'm declining it here to keep it from appearing as an open feature, that doesn't mean you shouldn't propose it there - just make sure you have a strong use case.