# Make it possible to flag posts as wrong

Tags: feature-request

Presently the only ways to point out an error in a post are adding a comment
and editing the post. However comments are not very visible in particular if
a post has already many of them. Editing the post does not have this drawback,
but it still may not be what one really wants, in particular if one does not
know how to correct the error.

Therefore I propose to make it possible to set an "error flag" if one finds
an error in a post. --

- Such an error flag may show up as a warning sign on the
  left margin below the voting arrows.
- A description of the error could be displayed when clicking on
  or moving the mouse above that sign.
- I suggest to make an error flag bump the post like an edit, and also
  generate notifications to the same people as an edit (plus the OP of
  the question, if an answer is flagged).
- I suggest that error flags could be removed when editing the flagged post.
- It should be possible to search posts with error flags.

This feature request is motivated by the thread [Dealing with possible incorrectness](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1342/dealing-with-possible-incorrectness).
I originally posted it as a proposal [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1053/big-list-of-feature-requests-and-suggestions-for-a-fantasy-mo-3-0/1349#1349), and turned it into a formal feature request
following a suggestion by Francois G. Dorais.

**Update:** Proposal withdrawn due to rejection by community -- see poll below.

Comment: Should it be visible which user flagged? [IMO, yes.]

Comment: How many points would you suggest as the minimum for the privilege of setting error flags?

Comment: @quid: Obviously yes.

Comment: @Gerry: Good question. -- On the one hand one could argue to treat it like the other flags (anyone with at least 15 points can flag), and on the other one could argue to treat it like an edit (>= 2000 points to perform it immediately, anyone can make a suggestion subject to approval).

Comment: Apart from the bumping, this isn't really more useful than commenting.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Isn't bumping one of the main points?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I'm not sure. But MO doesn't really suffer from overly long, boring comment threads AFAIK.

Comment: The voting on the original proposal [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1053/big-list-of-feature-requests-and-suggestions-for-a-fantasy-mo-3-0/1349#1349) and on this post differs significantly. -- Is there any difference between the posts which explains this?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker this proposal originated in [a discussion how to draw attention to potential errors](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1342/dealing-with-possible-incorrectness). The problem to be solve (in some people's opinion at least) is that on an *old* post a *new* comment will not be seen much, except by OP who gets notified. Typically this should also be sufficient, but if OP is for example unrespeonsive one might want to draw other's attention to the situation so that it can be evaluated which claim seems to be right.

Comment: @quid Sure, but it is not clear why many people should see such a comment. There is a risk that some people saw an old answer, "learned" something wrong in it and never revisited the question, so they will take their confusion to the grave. I doubt this is a big issue. The other thread was among other things about reduced visibility because the wrong answer was upvoted too much, something that should not be a problem. In a place for professional mathematics, people can be assumed to consume the material carefully. IMHO

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the *main* reason why I think having visibilty is relevant is so that more people can opine which of the contradictory claims is *correct*. In the other thread I gave a reason why it can even be relevant to highlight an actual *correction.*  But if somebody *claims* there is an error somewhere, and the person having supposedly commited the error does not acknowledge this (or even contradicts it) then I think in most cases it is in the best interest of both to get extra opinions. Even when being careful it can be difficult for some reader to decide on their own.

Comment: @quid I'm sure there are situations where this is an issue. But the changes to the system are not small ones and I'm not sure it is worth the effort. I would be very, very surprised if this would actually be implemented.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Put differently the main use of this flag in my mind is not to highlight cases of 'clear' errors but for cases where somebody is convinced there is an error but there is no straightforward way to prove it/convince everybody, and the claim might also be incorrect. I think of it more like a flag to "challenge a claim" than to "mark an error". If one wants a more positive spin one could also consider it as an "urgent request for clarification."

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker sorry for yet another comment, the second was written before seeing you reply. I'd guess technically it is rather simple to get something like this using existing things. Also socially (ie the idea how the site should work) it seems to follow the main idea for evaluation. Evaluation is done via opinion of others (via votes). In some cornercases voting might not work anymore, thus some mechanism for another round of opinion/voting. That being said: IMO, the idea is good but it is not very important to have this either. Chances are it will not be implemented, but who knows.

Comment: @quid I largely agree, I just think it is more productive to try to find a way to archive this with the existing capabilities.

Comment: What I see as a problem is a discrepancy between the intended semantics (quoting quid, “cases where somebody is convinced there is an error but there is no straightforward way to prove it/convince everybody, and the claim might also be incorrect”) and the proposed implementation: a sign below the voting arrows would very much suggest that this is a verdict officially sanctioned by the community, rather than some individual’s opinion. I would find it more adequate if the sign could appear near a regular *comment* explicating the alleged error.

Comment: In particular, I am concerned about the potential of abuse of the flag.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek what form of abuse do you have in mind?  (One could attach a cost like for downvotes if it is just about using it too much.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I doubt abuse would be a serious concern -- if something is flagged as an error which is no actual error, anyone who can edit the post could remove the flag.

Comment: @Francois: Given the outcome of the poll which I think is sufficiently clear, I consider my proposal as rejected.

Comment: Thanks for doing this Stefan. It wasn't clear that the community would respond this way. Unfortunately, it is still unclear to me whether the community is simply adverse to marking things wrong or to something else.

Comment: Here is an alternative idea that might worth looking at: in place of flagging for being incorrect we can ask for a feature where users can publicly endorse an answer, so if there is a incorrect answer with more upvotes than the correct one an expert can endorsed the correct one to make it clear it has been verified and also to draw attention to it. (This is already possible by commenting so it is more an issue of representation, we can move the list of people who have endorsed or to the top of the comment thread. It should be possible to do this with no modification to the system and using a

Comment: userscript and the userscript can also add a button for endorsing, users who do not use the script will simply see something like "endorsed by X". We can also implement something similar for stating the answer is incorrect. Search can also be supported by using the existing search or Data Explorer.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vote here if you disagree with introducing error flags, and think the proposal should be withdrawn.

Comment: I downvoted this as I am in favor of the proposal. In principle it would be better if one only upvoted in such poll situations (and on meta.math.SE this is always done like this or at least it is directly suggested to do so). Yet since others already downvoted other answers it seems necessary to also do so not to have a biased voting due to different 'voting rules.' [More generally, while I know where it comes from and was well intentioned, I think in this case offering the answers for voting did more harm than good.]

Answer (score 1):

Vote here if you agree with introducing error flags as such, but not in the proposed form.

Comment: @the first voter: So, a negative vote here means that you either agree with error flags in the proposed form, or you don’t agree with error flags at all, but you are not sure which of the two?

Answer (score -2):

Vote here if you agree with the suggestion as posted by OP.