# searching mathematical formulae like in Zentralblatt Math

Tags: feature-request, searching

It would be nice if searching mathematical formulae like Zentralblatt Math http://zbmath.org/formulae/ could be implemented.

Comment: Note brief discussion of this suggestion at the deleted answer at http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1053/big-list-of-feature-requests-and-suggestions-for-a-fantasy-mo-3-0

Comment: This uses something called [MathWebSearch](http://trac.mathweb.org/MWS), which seems to be an experimental project. Perhaps someone should ask them if they'd be interested in ingesting the MathOverflow corpus.

Comment: Related: [Is there any third party search engine for MathOverflow?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3082)