# Any chance of a "save for later / TODO" feature?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, bookmarks, saves

Sometimes when browsing MO questions I have the need to "save for later" for various reasons. There is a *star* for favoriting questions, it would be very useful to have "TODO" labels beyond just the *favorite* label for marking questions (because the favorites list might be already too long, and the TODO questions can eventually get lost in it).

> Is there any chance for such a feature ever becoming available?

Those who use feedly.com or other newsreaders will be familiar with such a feature.

Comment: I think you can just open a browser tab for every question or other page you'd like to revisit in the near future -- hence I don't think there is particular need for such feature (though of course it wouldn't harm either ...).

Comment: Stefan, these workarounds are what I've been using, but because they are not a "solution" I started looking for alternatives. Given how useful is "star" and other "labels" that one can attach to emails in gmail (not for everybody, but a pretty large number of people do find such things useful), I think desiring even a partial ability to have labels beyond just "favorite" is pretty reasonable.

Comment: Here is a related feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). And this userscripts might be worth looking at if you use Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215). (I will also mention my question - although it was related mainly to editing: [What do you use to mark questions that need editing when you want to avoid excessive bumping?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316745))

Answer (score 3):

The feature called "bookmarks" was recently completely overhauled by Stack Exchange and it is now called saves:

- [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019)
- [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#375078) - October 2022
- Help Center: [How do I use saves?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/saves)

One of the changes is that now you can organize your saves to several lists and give them any names you wish. And you can also add a private note to each of the saved posts.

You can find some other useful links in the corresponding tag-info both [on this meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/saves/info) and [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info).