# Improve management tools of favorite and upvoted questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, up-votes, bookmarks

Here is my wish list:

When one marks a question as favorite or upvotes it, give a chance to:

- Mark the question with a private tag.
- Add a private comment to the question. Its length could be limited in the same way as the length of usual comments.
- Add an option to mark an answer as favorite, especially when there are many answers.
- Then add the ability to search questions by private tags and comments.

How would it work:

- The tags would sort questions/answers into most general categories of why I like them. These would be defined by each user. For example I would have: research, teaching, fun, think_about_it_in_a_distant_future,...
- The comments would indicate a specific reason why I find a question/answer interesting. Often, after some time, I can't recall what so interesting had I seen in it. Often this is some association that hit me in the first reading but then I forgot it.

One side effect of such improvement: I would become more generous in upvoting when not having to worry that I won't find those really great questions/answers obscured by, also upvoted/favoritized, just a bit interesting ones.

Comment: A couple related feature requests on Meta Stack Exchange: [Private tags or other private searchable annotations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129366), and [Private notes on questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76759).

Comment: There is also this related feature request on the main meta: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944)

Comment: This is now partially implemented - there is a new feature called saves. So one can split the saved questions and answers into several lists. AFAICT it is not possible to have the same post in several lists. And no possibility of a private comment, either. (Here is another related question on this meta: [Any chance of a "save for later / TODO" feature?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1601))