# Are my comments searchable?

Tags: support, comments, searching, profile-page

My activity page in particular contains "All actions" tab; all my comments are there. Can I search for, say, a specific word there?

A wonderful [answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3267/41291) by Martin Sleziak to my question [Is it possible to search for posts/questions of an user $X$ commented on/answered by the user $Y$?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3266/41291) actually contains this as a particular case but involves using some SEDE queries, and I thought that for this particular case there might be more immediate way to search just the list of my own comments.

Comment: An older question on this site: [Searching for comments](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3247). For searching only in comments by a specific user you can use something like this: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1074444/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-a-given-word?userid=41291&word=comment), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1074444/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-a-given-word?userid=41291&word=comment). However, since you are asking about a way to do this without SEDE, I am leaving this just as a comment (not as an answer).

Comment: In case it is useful, here is also *case insensitive* version of that query: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1261690/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-the-given-word-case-insensitive?userid=41291&word=comment), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1261690/comments-by-a-specific-users-containing-the-given-word-case-insensitive?userid=41291&word=comment). And I'll also add a link to a related feature request: [Can I search my comments using some keyword(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148066)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with Google, not with the search box here on SE.