# I can not find one question I have already asked

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, searching

I had already asked a question as follows:
"Is there a one dimensional foliation of a two dimensional manifold whose foliation groupoid is diffeomorphic to a 3 sphere with two north pole. The latter is constructed as follows: We take a disjoint union of two 3_ spheres S,S' and identify  each point $x$ different from the North pole of S to the same point at S'. So we get a 3 sphere with two North poles. It is a non Hausdorff 3 manifold which is constructed in the similar way as construction of a line with 2 origin"
Could you please help me to find my question. It has at least 2 tags [foliation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/foliation) and [groupoids](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/groupoids).
I searched my questions but I did not find that question.
Thank you

Comment: I undeleted the question (the one found by Martin Sleziak). It was autodeleted, but it had no negative feedback.

Comment: Of course, one should keep in mind that if the question still fulfills [the criteria for roomba](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba), it will be deleted the next time the script runs. (AFAICT this basically meant that t will be deleted again if it doesn't get an upvote or at least two comments.)

Comment: @StefanKohl Dear Stefan Thank you very much for undeletting my question

Comment: Stack Exchange recently (2022) changed how this works - and now there is a way to get a list of all your deleted questions/deleted answers. For more details see here: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254) (And I guess, since now there is this new functionality, maybe this question could be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3254/can-i-somewhere-see-my-own-deleted-questions)

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that the question you're looking is this one: [One dimensional foliation of surfaces with prescribed graph of foliation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181371/one-dimensional-foliation-of-surfaces-with-prescribed-graph-of-foliation).

The question is deleted. You should be able to see it from the above link - since it is your own question. (The users like me - who are below 10k reputation points - cannot see the deleted question. But luckily enough, there is a [snapshot in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907145338/https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181371/one-dimensional-foliation-of-surfaces-with-prescribed-graph-of-foliation).)

The way you could have found the question is to [look at the list of the deleted questions tagged (groupoids) and (foliations)](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1098355/deleted-questions-having-the-given-two-tags?tag1=groupoids&tag2=foliations). In this list you do not see the titles, only links. But since there are only 4 question, it is not too much trouble to go through them one by one. (In the list you can also see that this particular question was created in September 2014 and deleted in September 2015 and it had score 0 at the time of the deletion.) And, of course, you can also check whether some of the other questions in this list is yours. I will add that on Mathematics there are no [deleted questions with those two tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1098355/deleted-questions-having-the-given-two-tags?tag1=groupoids&tag2=foliations). Checking all [deleted questions tagged foliations](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/968721/deleted-questions-posted-between-two-dates-with-a-specific-tag?Date1=2000-01-01&Date2=3000-01-01&tagname=foliations) or all [deleted questions tagged groupoids](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/968721/deleted-questions-posted-between-two-dates-with-a-specific-tag?Date1=2000-01-01&Date2=3000-01-01&tagname=groupoids) would be more work - in both cases there are about 50 questions - but it is still doable.

Some additional remarks:

- Naturally, you can search for [your questions](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A36688+is%3Aq+%5Bgroupoids%5D+%5Bfoliations%5D) or [all questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/groupoids+foliations) tagged with these two tags. But that search won't show you the deleted questions.
- 10k+ users can [add the search modifier deleted:1](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=%5Bgroupoids%5D+%5Bfoliations%5D+deleted%3A1) to any search and in that way they can search among *their own* deleted posts. But this doesn't work for users below 10k. See also: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254)
- Maybe it is reasonable to save regularly all your posts and or at least links to all your posts. If you create such archive locally on your computer, you can search there or check which posts have been deleted since the last update of this "local archive". See also: [How to make sure your questions never disappear in a blackhole?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5003)
- Or if you do not want the hassle of saving all of your content, you can at least check from time to time whether some of your posts are in danger of being deleted by [roomba](https://mathoverflow.net/help/roomba). For example, by checking your questions which have score 0 and no answers, i.e. searching for [user:me answers:0 score:..0](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+answers%3A0+score%3A..0). You can also use various SEDE queries to get list of your own questions which are getting close to the criteria of auto-deletion: [score<=0 and no answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1428054/my-questions-in-danger-of-auto-delete-after-365-days?userid=36688), [score<=0, no answers and at most one comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1428056/my-questions-in-danger-of-auto-delete-after-365-days-considering-comments?userid=36688), [score<=0, no answers, at most one comment and not locked](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1475410/my-questions-in-danger-of-auto-delete-after-365-days-not-locked?userid=36688). (Of course, if somebody is interested in such thing, it is possible to make [similar queries for the whole site](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1428059/questions-in-danger-of-auto-delete-after-365-days-not-locked) rather than listing only posts of one particular user. Or one could restrict the list [to a specific tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1476497/questions-in-danger-of-auto-delete-after-365-days-not-locked-in-a-specific-tag?tagname=linear-algebra).)

Comment: Dear Martin Thank you very much for your very helpful answer

Comment: This answer is now basically outdated since now there is much easier way to see *your own* deleted posts. For details see: [Can I somewhere see my own deleted questions?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3254)
(I did not want to bump this question by a new edit - so I have mentioned this only in a comment instead.)