# Rep being recalculated: Qs get +10 now?

Tags: support, reputation

So now StackExchange [thinks questions are worth +10 rep again](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). [Here is a comment](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/#comment-429503) where a StackOverflow user noticed their rep jump by ~6k.

Just now I was presented with a banner announcing this change (and on more than one SE site).

[image: SE banner announcement of reputation recalculation]

Do we know when this rep recalculation will hit MathOverflow?

Comment: I came here specifically to ask the same question!

Comment: It already did, didn’t it?

Comment: It seems to have already hit me. I must confess that for silly reasons I'd been looking forward to 20k, and aiming to get onto page 3 of the all-time leaderboard, but ... not like this.

Comment: congratulations to Joseph O'Rourke, who gained a staggering 40.000 rep. points!

Comment: (Anyone else kind of feel that answers **are** worth more than questions, when it comes to MO? Not that I would push very strongly for this, but the tone/claims in https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/ grate slightly)

Comment: @YemonChoi to my mind, I'm just getting back all the rep "they" took from me when the first change happened, and happy to be getting back the tools I lost at that time.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: That's because I've asked 640 questions. :-)

Comment: This resolved the highest voted answer here: [Big list of feature requests and suggestions for a fantasy MO 3.0](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1053#1054). (Most likely unintentionally.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recalculation is being processed in parallel across the entire network. Since it's run per user, some users on a site might get the change before others. We also had technical difficulties that have slowed the process down a bit. Hopefully it will be done for everyone across the network in a few hours. (Hopefully not days, but I can't rule that out at the moment.)

Comment: OK, thanks. I imagined that processing time could have been a factor. But it also crossed my mind that MO's ... special relationship with SE could have also impacted things.

Comment: And it just hit me! (on main, but not meta, it seems)

Comment: @David, there's no such thing as points on meta, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It takes a while to sync. Get upvoted or something to fix it.

Comment: @wizz I don't know what you're talking about. I took David's comment to mean that he didn't see his numbers on meta increase, which puzzled me, because there aren't any numbers on meta, whether something is in sync or not. I don't know what there is to fix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The numbers are the same, but they're stored in separate databases, meaning one is copied to the other. Triggering another change should cause another copy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The little status bar on meta with my profile button had the old rep, while the analogous button on main had my new rep. It's now synced.

Comment: Since the fact that it takes some time for the reputation shown on meta to sync with the reputation on the main site, I'll add that according to the help center it is synchronized hourly: https://mathoverflow.net/help/whats-meta See also: [Reputation is causing confusion on Meta Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89633#89634) and [How long is the time of the transfer of the reputation value from the main to the meta site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6721)